# Given two matrices pick $\alpha$ to minimize the spectral radius

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, spectral-radius

Given two 2x2 matrices and the following problem without restrictions, which value of $\alpha$ minimizes the spectral radius (the absolute value of the maximum eigenvalue), of both matrices ($\alpha$ must be the same).

$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}*A^{t}*Qx$

$Q = \begin{bmatrix}1&\\&b\end{bmatrix} $

b between (0,1)

\begin{bmatrix}1&-\alpha\\1&-\alpha\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1&-\alpha\\b&-\alpha *b\end{bmatrix}

Comment: These matrices both have determinant zero. So it's easy to factor the characteristic polynomials and obtain the other eigenvalues.

Comment: @B It is not clear what you mean when you say that you want a value of $\alpha$ that minimizes both matrices simultaneously. For example, if we had the functions $f(x) = \alpha^2$ and $g(x) = (\alpha-1)^2$, then which single value of $\alpha$ minimizes $f$ **and** $g$?

Comment: Both matrices are rank-one. Therefore their traces are their only possibly nonzero eigenvalues. In turn, the absolute values of their traces, i.e., $|1-\alpha|$ and $|1-\alpha b|$, are their spectral radii. But obviously, unless $b=0$ or $b=1$, you cannot minimise $|1-\alpha|$ and $|1-\alpha b|$ simultaneously.

Comment: Why unless b = 1 or b = 0, I cannot minimise both spectral radiis?

Comment: @B By the way, I had a typo: that should read $f(\alpha) = \alpha^2$ and $g(\alpha) = (\alpha - 1)^2$

Comment: @B The other commenter's issue is the same as the one that I am having. In general, for a function $f(x)$ and a function $g(x)$, there is no value of $x$ that minimizes $f(x)$ **and** minimizes $g(x)$.

Comment: @B.Casals The unique global minimiser of $|1-\alpha|$ is $\alpha=1$. When $b\ne0,1$, the unique global minimiser of $|1-\alpha b|$ is $\alpha=\frac1b$. The two minimisers are different. Hence you cannot minimise both functions simultaneously.